# how can i call asp.net web service from blackberry application?

Tags: java, blackberry

Iam a beginner in blackberry applications 
I want simple code to call asp.net service from my bb application

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a SOAP Web Service or a RESTFul Service?

Answer (score 0):

KSOAP2 can be used it for Blackberry.

To call web services I use the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit (WTK) to generate stubs from your webservice's WSDL file, which should probably be http://192.168.1.14/ CG/authentication.asmx?wsdl for you.

You can then import the files that the WTK generates into your project to call your web methods using something along the lines of:

```
//Generated stub file
```

Service1Soap_Stub stub = new Service1Soap_Stub();

```
//Web service method
```

result = stub.methodName(param1, param2);